# Does FirePhp work well with FireBug 1.12.0?

Tags: php, firebug, firephp

I used firephp in my project well before yesterday.

After I upgrade Firefox to version 23.0.1 , the FireBug extension is upgraded to version 1.12.0 automatically, and I find firephp do not show the detail data in the console.

It still shows the brief data. I can not unfold it to see the detail.

I guess firebug changed the data structure, and the firephp need to be upgrade.

Comment: I'm not having any problems with FireFox 23.0.1, FirePHP 0.7.4 and FireBug 1.12.0. Do you have the same version of FirePHP?

Comment: What's FirePHP 0.7.4? The most recent version I see [here](http://www.firephp.org/) is 0.7.2. And yes, I got the same issue: no longer I can see the DB queries themselves, for example, only their summary row.

Comment: ... and clicking on this row gives me `node is null` message, when `Chrome errors` option is turned on.

Comment: For me in Firefox 23.0.1 (firebug 1.12.0 + firephp 0.7.2) logging not working. Alternative logging from Firebug Server API in Google Chrome extension working fine.

Answer (score 5):

If you are impatient type you can do a quick fix yourself.

- Open the FireBug xpi file with your favourite archive/zip manager. For linux users, you should find the file here:

  ~/.mozilla/firefox/[unique-id].default/extensions/firebug@software.joehewitt.com.xpi
- Navigate to `/content/firebug/console/` in the archive/zip manager and open `consolePanel.js`
- Got to line 911 (this may differ slightly for minor version revisions). It should look like this:

  ```
  this.filterMatchSet.push(group);
  ```
- Add this before that line:

  ```
  if (typeof this.filterMatchSet == 'undefined')
  {
      this.filterMatchSet = [];
  }
  ```
- Save your change to the archive and restart FireFox

Comment: Thanks you very much, this fixed perfectly the problem !Using Iceweasel (25.0a2 ) , Firebug 1.12 and Firephp 9.7.2

Comment: @Kammy, could you list any debug that you're getting in the console tab of FireBug. Maybe you have a different issue that we can resolve.

Comment: @Tom I am on windows and having FF 23.0.1, Firebug 1.12.0 and Firephp 0.7.2. I did changes as you have mentioned and made zip and renamed it as xpi. It installed properly after restarting FF. But its still showing like before "Zend_Db_Profiler_Firebug (18 @ 0.27579 sec)" in blue non-expendable text in console.

Comment: @Kammy, If there is no error message then that iss unfortunately very hard to debug remotely. In my case I got the following error message "TypeError: this.filterMatchSet is undefined" which allowed me to track down the problem. Try expand the GET [URL] block in FireBug and click on the Headers tab. The raw FirePHP header information might have some information.

Comment: @Tom now I am doing same. I right click on that string of console and it gives me two options 1. use in command line 2. inspect in DOM panel. So i use second option which shows me window[19] array with all sql queries and related info

Comment: @Tom: You describe a different problem than the topic says. So I wonder if [Christoph's patched version](https://github.com/firephp/firephp-extension/issues/10#issuecomment-23741024) also fixes your problem. If not, it would be great if you posted it to the [FirePHP issue tracker](https://github.com/firephp/firephp-extension/issues) along with a reproducible test case.

Comment: I solve this issue by installing FirePHP 0.7.4 on windows https://s3.amazonaws.com/download.sourcemint.com/github.com/firephp/firephp-extension/-stream/stable/firephp-extension-0.7.4.xpi

Answer (score 2):

Firefox 23.0.1 + Firebug 1.12.0 + FirePHP 0.7.2 - the same versions set and the same problem... I checked [FirePHP forum](http://forum.firephp.org/) and there is [a topic about this issue](http://firephp.842658.n2.nabble.com/FirePHP-0-7-2-does-not-work-with-Firebug-1-12-0-under-Firefox-23-0-1-td7572767.html). Add-on author wrote there

> Will take a look in early September after I return from vacation. Thanks for reporting this issue.

so in few weeks problem will be resolved I hope. :)

Comment: You can test fix here: https://github.com/firephp/firephp-extension/issues/10#issuecomment-23741024

Comment: At least this patch fixes the problem for me. Thanks Chris!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this issue with firePHP isn't being fixed any time soon and firebug has been updated again. Tom's answer does work but as he only specified a line number that part doesn't work in the newer version of firebug as the line numbers doesn't line up with the old ones SO here is how to find the correct place to insert Tom's code:

Follow Tom's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18530316/769294

Then when you have the consolePanel.js open you want to find this function:

```
filterLogRow: function(logRow, scrolledToBottom)
{
    if (this.matchesFilter(logRow))
    {
        // Mark the groups, in which the log row is located, also as matched
        for (var group = Dom.getAncestorByClass(logRow, "logRow-group"); group;
            group = Dom.getAncestorByClass(group.parentNode, "logRow-group"))
        {
            Css.setClass(group, "contentMatchesFilter");
            // #################################################################
            // Add This line here
            // #################################################################
            if (typeof this.filterMatchSet == 'undefined') { this.filterMatchSet = []; }
            // #################################################################
            this.filterMatchSet.push(group);
        }
    }

    .......
},
```

As you can see I have added some comments around the line you need to add (from Tom's answer) and you can see where it needs to go.

Hope this helps for all the updates to firebug in the near future until firePHP is fixed. :)

Answer (score 1):

[The problem](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=6803) is fixed with Firebug 1.12.3.